# Efficient way to monitor a certain process in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, process

I would like to monitor a given process in a tool I'm writing.
The user can select an executable and the tool should be able to tell when that process is started and ended.

The only way I've been able to (somewhat) achieve this is using QProcess to run tasklist with a filter once in a while but this is requires a lot of work and is really not a solution.

Is there a good way to achieve this, especially without having to constantly check for running processes?

Edit:
Trying to compile the example from Microsofts documentation, I recieve the following errors:
`error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'DWORD' (aka 'unsigned long') loses information`

```
error: cast from 'BYTE*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'DWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int'} loses precision [-fpermissive]
     _tprintf( TEXT("\n     Base address   = 0x%08X"), (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr );
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I remove both prints, I recieve the following output (I'm only attaching a single process)

```
=====================================================
PROCESS NAME:  i
-------------------------------------------------------
  Process ID        = 0x00000BAC
  Thread count      = 4
  Parent process ID = 0x000047AC
  Priority base     = 8
  Priority class    = 32

     MODULE NAME:     i
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0xFFFF
     Ref count (p)  = 0xFFFF
     Base size      = 1048576

     MODULE NAME:     n
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0xFFFF
     Ref count (p)  = 0xFFFF
     Base size      = 2052096

     MODULE NAME:     K
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0xFFFF
     Ref count (p)  = 0xFFFF
     Base size      = 774144

     MODULE NAME:     K
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0xFFFF
     Ref count (p)  = 0xFFFF
     Base size      = 2916352

     MODULE NAME:     m
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x000F
     Ref count (p)  = 0x000F
     Base size      = 647168

     MODULE NAME:     Q
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 5787648

     MODULE NAME:     Q
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0003
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0003
     Base size      = 6524928

     MODULE NAME:     l
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0005
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0005
     Base size      = 106496

     MODULE NAME:     A
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 704512

     MODULE NAME:     G
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x000A
     Ref count (p)  = 0x000A
     Base size      = 172032

     MODULE NAME:     s
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 634880

     MODULE NAME:     w
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0004
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0004
     Base size      = 139264

     MODULE NAME:     g
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x000A
     Ref count (p)  = 0x000A
     Base size      = 1093632

     MODULE NAME:     R
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0007
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0007
     Base size      = 1224704

     MODULE NAME:     d
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 192512

     MODULE NAME:     m
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0002
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0002
     Base size      = 643072

     MODULE NAME:     l
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0004
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0004
     Base size      = 1454080

     MODULE NAME:     U
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x000A
     Ref count (p)  = 0x000A
     Base size      = 1703936

     MODULE NAME:     o
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0003
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0003
     Base size      = 1220608

     MODULE NAME:     u
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0008
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0008
     Base size      = 1048576

     MODULE NAME:     c
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0006
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0006
     Base size      = 3493888

     MODULE NAME:     S
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0002
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0002
     Base size      = 7610368

     MODULE NAME:     W
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 438272

     MODULE NAME:     l
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0004
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0004
     Base size      = 86016

     MODULE NAME:     M
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 118784

     MODULE NAME:     N
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 98304

     MODULE NAME:     U
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 188416

     MODULE NAME:     V
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 40960

     MODULE NAME:     W
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 159744

     MODULE NAME:     U
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 647168

     MODULE NAME:     C
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 49152

     MODULE NAME:     N
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 49152

     MODULE NAME:     S
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 163840

     MODULE NAME:     Q
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0002
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0002
     Base size      = 7151616

     MODULE NAME:     d
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 2506752

     MODULE NAME:     d
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0002
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0002
     Base size      = 995328

     MODULE NAME:     I
     Executable     = C
     Process ID     = 0x00000BAC
     Ref count (g)  = 0x0001
     Ref count (p)  = 0x0001
     Base size      = 196608

     THREAD ID      = 0x00002F84
     Base priority  = 8
     Delta priority = 0


     THREAD ID      = 0x00003E18
     Base priority  = 8
     Delta priority = 0


     THREAD ID      = 0x00001908
     Base priority  = 8
     Delta priority = 0


     THREAD ID      = 0x00005524
     Base priority  = 8
     Delta priority = 0
```

Comment: If all you need is limited to knowing when the process started and ended, you can use system() and a time keeping mechanism to do it. It's not very portable nor is it extendable.

Comment: How would I use system to check for another process?

Comment: You can use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) to create a snapshot of processes, threads, modules and heaps.

Comment: @LeoKlaus your question just asks about start and end times. System simply runs a process. So, you cant actually check for another process. If you do then you should edit your question and add that part.

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly. Sorry for the unclear phrasing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't even compile the example without modifications. Even when it compiles, the output is cryptic and I can't find a single process in it that is actually running on my system.

Comment: @LeoKlaus Ok, if you don't get it working you need to ask a specific question about it. I've used `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` many times on Windows for different purposes and don't remember having noticed anything in the MSDN documentation being wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I haven't worked with Windows Apis yet, so it's hard to be precise. I'll update my question and try to be more specific.

Comment: Use the WMI and register to be notified when your process gets created and terminated.